# Merge xml nodes of same type and display both results in C#

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, linq-to-xml

I have 2 XML elements(from same XML document) of the looking like this:

```
<Parent>
  <Child1>contentA</Child1>
  <Child2>contentB</Child2>      
</Parent>

<Parent>
  <Child1>contentC</Child1>
  <Child2>contentD</Child2>
</Parent>
```

What I have done:

```
var Data= from Parent in Parent.Elements("Parent").AsEnumerable()
select new
{
Child1=Parent.Elements("Child1").Value,
Child2=Parent.Elements("Child2").Value
}
```

This above snippet prints twice.

What I need to do is merge the content of the second Parent node with the first Parent node and display both the contents that would look like this:

```
<Parent>
  <Child1>contentA/contentC</Child1>
  <Child2>contentB/contentD</Child2>      
</Parent>
```

Comment: "In Memory" or do you need actual XML _Files_? In latter case, I'd recommend using [XSLT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/how-to-perform-an-xslt-transformation-by-using-an-assembly).

Comment: in XML Files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With LINQ I think you want to use Zip:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Root>
<Parent>
  <Child1>contentA</Child1>
  <Child2>contentB</Child2>      
</Parent>

<Parent>
  <Child1>contentC</Child1>
  <Child2>contentD</Child2>
</Parent>
</Root>");
    

            XElement newParent = new XElement("Parent",
                doc.Root.Elements("Parent").First().Elements().Zip(doc.Root.Elements("Parent").Skip(1).First().Elements(), (c1, c2) => new XElement(c1.Name, string.Format("{0}/{1}", c1.Value, c2.Value)))
                );

Console.WriteLine(newParent);
```

Gives

```
<Table>
  <Child1>contentA/contentC</Child1>
  <Child2>contentB/contentD</Child2>
</Table>
```

Or for the other input:

```
 doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Root>
        <Item>
          <TaxCode>TAX</TaxCode>
          <Amount>5499.00</Amount>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <TaxCode>SC </TaxCode>
          <Amount>12.50</Amount>
        </Item></Root>");


        XElement table = new XElement("Table",
                doc.Root.Elements("Item").First().Elements().Zip(doc.Root.Elements("Item").Skip(1).First().Elements(), (c1, c2) => new XElement(c1.Name, string.Format("{0}/{1}", c1.Value, c2.Value)))
                );

        Console.WriteLine(table);
```

you get

```
<Table>
  <TaxCode>TAX/SC </TaxCode>
  <Amount>5499.00/12.50</Amount>
</Table>
```

In your existing code with e.g. `from Item in OtherInfo.Elements("Item")` perhaps

```
   let items = OtherInfo.Elements("Item"),
       firstItem = items.First(),
       secondItem = items.Skip(1).First()
   return 
       firstItem.Elements().Zip(
         secondItem.Elements(),
         (i1, i2) => new XElement(i1.Name, string.Format("{0}/{1}", i1.Value, i2.Value)
        )
```

Comment: a table has been created already  'DataTable dt = ConvertToDataTable(Data); '. I just need the alteration alone. The Data contains a elements of xml which have been converted to rows and columns later.

Comment: I have shown the output in a table itself. Hope its clear.

Comment: @alphacon, perhaps stick to one issue in one question, if you tag as LINQ and LINQ to XML and also want some integration with DataTable, better raise a second question for the second issue. I can only make suggestion based on the code and tags you use in the question, not some comment telling me later that a DataTable has to be used. The Zip method, I think, does the merge you want, whether you stuff that into an XElement("Table"), as I did for the example, or use the result elsewhere, shouldn't matter.

Comment: I should have mentioned it as datatable, it was my mistake. But I am very sure that I am in need of your help. Please don't mistake me.

Comment: As per the latest edit in question this is my requirement.

Comment: Perhaps show a minmal sample including any DataTable you receive the XML from. Currently the question's code doesn't show any use of a DataTable.

Comment: Added as per your requirement.

Comment: At which point in your current code do you have e.g. `<Item><TaxCode>TAX</TaxCode><Amount>5499.00</Amount> </Item>`? I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: I am parsing my xml code in which the code that you have asked exists. when i parse this into Datatable I require the above.

Comment: Does `from Item in OtherInfo.Elements("Item")` select exactly those two `Item` elements you show? Or more?